# C Sendto doesn't work when doing it repeatedly

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm facing a weird problem when using sendto() in C. I have this code:

```
struct sockaddr_in currSocket;
int currSocketLength = sizeof(currSocket);
memset((char *)&currSocket, 0, sizeof(currSocket));
currSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
currSocket.sin_port = htons(serverPortNumber);
// add the server IP address
inet_aton(serverIP, &currSocket.sin_addr);

int send_result = sendto(masterSocket, bufferToSend , 1000, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &currSocket, currSocketLength);
if (send_result < 0) {
    perror("Something is wrong");
}
bzero(bufferToSend, 1000);
```

This works great when I send data the first time in `bufferToSend`. However, if I want to send data again the exact same way (following the code above - create the socket and send it there), it doesn't get received. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Edit:
After looking into it some more, I've realized it's because my IP address string is wrong because it's being overwritten. It seems to have it's value change after I do a previous read.

```
// here the IP address is fine
printf("%s\n", ipAddress);
char bufferFromSocket[512];
int amount_read = read(masterSocket, bufferFromSocket, 512);
// here the IP address is overwritten by whatever is in bufferFromSocket
printf("%s\n", ipAddress);
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you describe how you verified that the data fails to send, as opposed to the problem being on the receiver side?

Comment: The program above is supposed to be a tunnel that handles multiple requests. Every time one comes in, I create a currSocket (as shown above) and send it to the appropriate spot. I tested the receiver app without the tunnel and it is able to receive messages, so that's how I know it works.

Comment: Suggest you grab a copy of Wireshark and see what's happening on the actual wire. That will let you know whether the problem lies with that code or over on the receiver.

Comment: I copy-pasted this code without modification, added ~20 lines around it to make it compile and run, and it successfully sent data multiple times. Please take the time to turn your snippet into a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that you can be sure that you include all relevant information.

Comment: Hmm ok, maybe it's some other part of my code then. I will investigate. Thank you @thatotherguy

Comment: It could still be this part but with different assumptions about how e.g. the connection was set up. A MCVE helps uncover unstated assumptions.

Comment: @thatotherguy I looked into it more and it's because the IP address is wrong, for some reason it get's overwritten by a buffer when I Call read to get data from another socket. Edited the original post

Comment: Where does `ipAddress` come from? Where does it go?

Comment: @Ry- It's a char* which is valid when I originally print it.

Comment: Okay. Where does it come from, and where else are you using it?

Comment: I figured out. I didn't allocate enough space for ipAddress.

Answer (score -1):

I hadn't allocated enough space for ipAddress. Had it as a pointer, when it should have been a char[] and I copy to it using strcpy.